# How can I find the Thread Local Storage (TLS) of a Windows Process Thread?

Tags: windows, winapi, thread

The Thread Local Storage (TLS) contains static or global values for a thread. Those values can be very important to find reliable references to memory structures when the memory locations are not static.

I would like to get the Thread Local Storage of another process.

The TLS should be at [[FS:0x2C] in the Thread Information Block (TIB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block). Though I quite don't understand how the FS register works. I guess I have to find the TIB Base address first? I think I can find it in the Thread Context I can get with [WINAPI GetThreadContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I am a little bit overwhelmed.

Comment: Are you looking for ways to access it in the same process? different process? Clarify your situation and what exactly you need to do.

Comment: I try to do it for a different process. I will update my question for clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [`GetThreadSelectorEntry()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Pseudocode:

```
GetThreadContext(hThread, &context);
GetThreadSelectorEntry(hThread, context.SegFs, &selectorEntry);
ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (selectorEntry.BaseLow | (selectorEntry.HighWord.Bytes.BaseMid << 0x10) | (selectorEntry.HighWord.Bytes.BaseHi << 0x18)) + 0x2C, &pTLS, sizeof(pTLS), &numberOfBytesRead);
```

You can see the function `GetProcessEntryPointAddress()` [here](http://nerdworks.in/downloads/myselfdel.c) for some sample code that does something similar.

Comment: thank you, it worked like a charm :) I didn't know `GetThreadSelectorEntry()`

Comment: @jason-geffner 10 years have gone by and your link is now dead. You don't happen to have a copy of the content? The answers to such questions never get old :)

Comment: @Benni, you're in luck! See https://blogorama.nerdworks.in/content/images/nerdworks/downloads/myselfdel.c

Comment: thanks a lot! I found it hard to find commented sample code for it.